# diamondback stereo_image_proc and GPU

Tags: ros, cuda, gpu, stere-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The wg-ros-pkg in cturtle has a sandbox directory with stereo_image_proc_gpu. This same package is not present in diamondback's wg-ros-pkg. Where did it go? Did it advance out of the sandbox, or did it get cut completely? Are the GPU-ready packages in diamondback gathered in some centralized area, or is there perhaps a list of them?

Thanks,
Sean

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9769/diamondback-stereo_image_proc-and-gpu/) by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 753 on 2011-04-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sean-

Victor from OpenCV and I set up that package for benchmarking. If you look at the code, that package uses a modified version of stereo image proc that runs on the GPU with CUDA. That package was never designed to be released.

I believe OpenCV has released GPU implementations of several algorithms, including stereo block matching (or they may be scheduled to release them soon). I don't think these algorithms have been integrated with ROS's stereo_image_proc, but you could probably patch it fairly easily since they probably have identical API's. If you create any patches, open a ticket in ros-pkg.

Kevin

---

Originally posted by [watts](https://answers.ros.org/users/99/watts/) with karma: 584 on 2011-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wpi_igvc12](https://answers.ros.org/users/1424/wpi_igvc12/) on 2012-01-19**:
Does anyone know if this is currently being worked on by someone?